# In an Ember framework, How do I remove the Pod folder name from the URL

Tags: ember.js

I'm using Ember POD syntax to organize my Ember application.

[image: picture of files organized under POD directory named 'main']

Is it possible to remove the pod directory from appearing in the browser URL?  If so, how?

See picture.

[image: picture of the pod directory in the URL path]

This is my current router.js file

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('main', function() {
    this.route('about');
    this.route('focus', function() {
      this.route('show');
    });
    this.route('projects', function() {
      this.route('show');
    });
    this.route('articles', function() {
      this.route('show', {path: '/:id'});
    });
    this.route('contact');
  });
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: Consider finding opportunities to paste actual code into your question and describe what you're trying to do with the code in the question (e.g., "Is it possible to remove the pod directory for the `main` route?"). The images are a nice supplement to that though, so I'd leave those links in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `main` route can have a `path` of `''`.

```
this.route('main', { path: '' }, function() {
  this.route('about');
  // etc...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Chirs.   That solved it.  Much appreciated. Per your comment, I added my original router.js code in the question to help others.